# Fourier shift theorem: What happens when the shift is very large (e.g., multiplying a signal by a shifting bandpass filter)?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I'm trying to apply the Fourier transform shift theorem and the convolution theorem to a problem. I thought I was using them logically, but I have a case where my logic has to break.

I have a given signal, which I multiply by a rectangular window function (the window starts off centered on the origin) and then I Fourier transform (FT) the result. The FT of the window function is a sinc function, so my end result is a convolution of the FT of my signal and the sinc function (Gibbs ringing --- I'm okay with this so far).

I'd then like to move the window to a different position along my signal (not centered on the origin) and FT that region instead. From the FT shift theorem, the FT of the shifted window is still a sinc function, but with an added phase offset.
$$\mathcal{F}\{f(t-t_0)\}=F(\omega)e^{-j\omega t_0}$$
So I multiply my signal by this shifted window and take the FT. The end result is a convolution of the FT of my signal and the phase-offset sinc function.

My thought was that the phase offset should have no affect on the magnitude of my result. Therefore, the magnitude of my end result will always be the same, regardless of the position of the window function. This clearly cannot be the case. For example, if I shift the window so far in time that I only FT a region of noise. My above logic would say that the magnitude of the result is the same as if my window were centered (this cannot be true).

Where does my thinking fall apart?

Comment: Perhaps your confusion stems from thinking that it is a phase offset when it is actually a linear phase? That is, $e^{-j\omega t_0}$ is not a phase offset; rather, it has a phase that is linear in $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There's still something I'm missing. Even with a linear phase across the sinc function in frequency space, isn't the magnitude unchanged? (i.e., the magnitude will be the same at a point on the sinc regardless if it's all real and zero imaginary, or all imaginary and zero real, or any phase in between - so including a linear phase shift doesn't affect magnitude?)

Comment: It won't affect the magnitude of the frequency domain samples, but it will affect the magnitude of the time domain ones. Is that what you are getting at?